# Why doesn't Mi Yodeya allow you to post a question in a foreign language?

Tags: discussion, scope, language

I can barely read and write English, I only know Gujarati, so could Mi Yodeya allow me to post a question in Gujarati

અગાઉથી આભાર

Comment: Nope. But you could try using online translation tools.

Comment: તમારું સ્વાગત છે.

Comment: તમે આ ટિપ્પણીઓને કેવી રીતે અસરકારક ઓનલાઇન અનુવાદ સાધનો પર આધારિત હોય છે તે નક્કી કરી શકે.

Comment: આશા છે કે તમે અને અન્ય ગુજરાતી બોલતા લોકો સાઇટ વાપરવા માટે નક્કી કરે છે. તે સાઇટ પર 65 મિલિયન વપરાશકર્તાઓ ઉમેરો કરી શકે છે!

Comment: પરંતુ ભગવાન વિશ્વમાં બધી ભાષાઓ બનાવવા ન હતી, જેથી હું ઓછામાં ઓછા ગુજરાતી મોટે ભાગે મારા પ્રશ્નો લખી શકે છે અને અહીં અને ત્યાં થોડો ઇંગલિશ માં ફેંકવું

Comment: જો તમે કરવા માંગો છો મને તમારી ટિપ્પણીઓ જાણ કરવામાં આવશે, તમારા વપરાશકર્તા નામ પહેલાં @ મૂકો. @mevaqesh જેવા.

Comment: અમે તમને અહીં છે કરવા માંગો છો, પરંતુ સાઇટ જે લોકો માત્ર ઇંગલિશ વાત [સમાવવા માટે રાખવાનો છે](http://meta.judaism.stackexchange.com/a/4081/8775). કારણ કે હું કરું છું, અને તે કામ કરે છે જોઈ તમે, અનુવાદ સાધનો ઉપયોગ કરવાનો પ્રયાસ કરો સ્વાગત છે.

Comment: @mevaqesh પરંતુ ભગવાન વિશ્વમાં બધી ભાષાઓ બનાવવા ન હતી, જેથી હું ઓછામાં ઓછા ગુજરાતી મોટે ભાગે મારા પ્રશ્નો લખી શકે છે અને અહીં અને ત્યાં થોડો ઇંગલિશ માં ફેંકવું

Comment: પોસ્ટ્સ ગુજરાતી માં લખાયેલ કરી શકાતી નથી. લોકો ટેવ સમજે છે. હું દિલગીર છીએ જો મારા ટિપ્પણીઓ સ્પષ્ટ નથી. ગુજરાતી મારી પ્રથમ ભાષા નથી :) શું તમે ઈશ્વર અને ભાષા વિશે લખ્યું છે તે સાચું છે. જો કે, દરેક વ્યક્તિ હજુ પણ સમજવા માટે જરૂર છે.

Comment: @mevaqesh - You know Gujarati??? Wow the things I learn each day.

Comment: @EzraHoerster હું માત્ર અનુવાદ સાધનોનો ઉપયોગ. :)

Comment: @mevaqesh - 
મેં જોયુ

Comment: Related, and with the problems related to using machine-translation for this purpose noted: http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/118667/wouldnt-user-improved-google-translate-output-of-stack-overflow-be-a-better-opt